# Why I have to specify the Class name on a PHP Adapter

Tags: php, adapter

While creating a PHP Adapter, all sources I read uses the following syntax:

```
class Adapter {
  private $object;

  public function __construct(**OriginalClass** $obj) {
    $this->object = $obj;
  ...
```

What I don't understand is why I have to state the name of the class in the adapter constructor argument, just before the object itself. Couldn't I just use  `... __construct($obj) {`, since the object will be already instantiated when passed as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `**OriginalClass**` part is called [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) that restrict the constructor argument to object of a particular class. So, in your case it is making sure your Adapter class can only be used for a particular class.

Answer (score 1):

Stating the class name forces the accepted parameter instance.

```
__construct(OriginalClass $obj)
```

This forces `OriginalClass` to be passed. If you pass `DifferentClass` as a constructor parameter, the code will fail to compile/run.